# how to handle touch on smartphone's browsers - javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to handle touch listener on smartphones. 
my codes works fine with `mousedown`,`mousemove`,`mouseup`,`mouseout` on web browsers.

```
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var p = get_mouse_position(event);
        for( var i=0; i<4; i++ ) {
            var x = points[i][0];
            var y = points[i][1];
            if( p.x < x + 10 && p.x > x - 10 && p.y < y + 10 && p.y > y - 10 ) {
                drag = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(drag == null) { return; }
        var p = get_mouse_position(event);
        points[drag][0] = p.x;
        points[drag][1] = p.y;
        prepare_lines(ctx2, points, true);
        draw_canvas(ctx, ctx1, ctx2);
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(drag == null) { return; }
        var p = get_mouse_position(event);
        points[drag][0] = p.x;
        points[drag][1] = p.y;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx1.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var s = (new Date()).getTime();
        op.draw(points);
document.getElementById("ms").innerHTML = ( (new Date()).getTime() - s );
        prepare_lines(ctx2, points);
        draw_canvas(ctx, ctx1, ctx2);
        drag = null;
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        drag = null;
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        drag = null;
    }, false);
```

like this demo:

http://www.html5.jp/test/perspective_canvas/demo1_en.html

https://github.com/wanadev/perspective.js/

but my codes doesn't work on smartphone's browsers.

I added `touchstart`,`touchmove`,`touchend` listener like same codes on click listeners. but on smartphone's browsers my edges dosn't move at all.

touch listerns:

```
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var p = get_mouse_position(event);
        for( var i=0; i<4; i++ ) {
            var x = points[i][0];
            var y = points[i][1];
            if( p.x < x + 10 && p.x > x - 10 && p.y < y + 10 && p.y > y - 10 ) {
                drag = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }, false);

    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(drag == null) { return; }
        var p = get_mouse_position(event);
        points[drag][0] = p.x;
        points[drag][1] = p.y;
        prepare_lines(ctx2, points, true);
        draw_canvas(ctx, ctx1, ctx2);
    }, false);

    canvas.addEventListener('touchend', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        if(drag == null) { return; }
        var p = get_mouse_position(event);
        points[drag][0] = p.x;
        points[drag][1] = p.y;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx1.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var s = (new Date()).getTime();
        op.draw(points);
document.getElementById("ms").innerHTML = ( (new Date()).getTime() - s );
        prepare_lines(ctx2, points);
        draw_canvas(ctx, ctx1, ctx2);
        drag = null;
    }, false);
```

I want to handle 4-edges on smartphone's browsers  like web browsers. but I can't move 4-edges on smartphone's browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [TouchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent) might be composed of multiple Touch objects (a.k.a multitouch).
These different [Touch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch) objects are available through the `.touches` [TouchList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchList) property of the Event.

Only these objects will hold the coordinates you are interested in, and thus, in your handler, you need to pick one of these Touch object, this is generally the first one (single-touch application).

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// attach all our handlers
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', handleDown);
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', handleDown);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleUp);
document.addEventListener('touchend', handleUp);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMove);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', handleMove);

var mouse = {
  lastX: null,
  lastY: null,
  x: null,
  y: null,
  down: false
};

// Here we want to check whether it is a touch event or a mouse event
function update_coords(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var ev;
  // touch event?
  if (evt.touches && evt.touches.length) {
    ev = evt.touches[0];
  } else ev = evt; // mouse
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

  // update our mouse object
  mouse.lastX = mouse.x;
  mouse.lastY = mouse.y;
  mouse.x = ev.clientX - rect.left;
  mouse.y = ev.clientY - rect.top;
}

function handleDown(evt) {
  mouse.down = true;
  update_coords(evt);
  draw();
}

function handleUp(evt) {
  mouse.down = false;
  mouse.lastX = mouse.lastY = mouse.x = mouse.y = null;
}

function handleMove(evt) {
  if (mouse.down) {
    update_coords(evt);
    draw();
  }
}

function draw() {
  if(mouse.lastX === null) return;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(mouse.lastX, mouse.lastY);
  ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

---

<sub>To test on a mobile device, please switch to the *full site* version of Stackoverflow (at the bottom of the page) or try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zL1erh5o/).</sub>

Comment: @S.M_Emamian fast reading the code in given link, you inverted `event` and `canvas` in either `function getTouchPos(canvasDom, touchEvent)` or `var p = getTouchPos(event,canvas)` in all your touch event listeners.

Comment: I changed the parameters. solved but my canvas doesn't render again.

Comment: I don't know what this means and I won't be able to help further since I lack an MCVE where one could debug your code. The only thing I can give you as an help is to read your console's output after you connected your mobile device to the remote debugger of your desktop browser.